# Change default repr in interactive python from builtins.repr to reprlib.repr

Tags: python, console, interactive, repr

On the interactive Python prompt, when I don't bind the output of an expression `foo` to a name, Python will write the output of `builtins.repr(foo)` to the terminal.

In newer versions of Python, there exists [an alternative `repr` implementation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/reprlib.html) that will not flood the screen for objects with a long string representation, like this:

```
In [297]: import random, string, reprlib

In [298]: long_str = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(1000))

In [299]: print(repr(long_str))
'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'

In [300]: print(reprlib.repr(long_str))
'LcOKLSfEifoh...CKmpTICujAJsA'

In [301]: long_str
Out[301]: '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'
```

Can I somehow tell Python to use `reprlib.repr` instead of `builtin.repr` for representing un-assigned output in the interactive prompt? I'm interested preferably in answers that work for any Python shell, or otherwise in answers that work at least for IPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is likely `sys.display_hook`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook.